# tvOS load lcr image file in a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, tvos, xcode7.1beta

Using tvOS, how am I able to load a LCR image file in an image view using objective-c? I tried something like this but it didn't work out:

```
NSURL *imagePostedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"image"]];

[self.img setImageWithURL:imagePostedURL];
```

Comment: are you getting any error messages in the console?

Comment: Nope, the image just doesn't show up. Do you know if there is a different method to load LCR image files besides URLWithString?

Comment: try his     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:<path>];
    self.img = image;

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was facing exactly same issue but I am doing it in Swift. I could find a work around for this problem and here is link of my question and answer:
[Unable to load LCR image in tvOS apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170120/unable-to-load-lcr-image-in-tvos-apps)

Basically you need to save .lcr file in local system and then use it. I explained with code sample in my answer.